Search & Match 2 sheets & 2 columns, return value from 3rd column
I am trying to find a formula that will search for identical data in Column A (Sheet 1) and Column B (Sheet 2), when the matching data is found, I need the data from Sheet 1 Column B to be returned / sent to Sheet 2 Column D. I was able to do this if I combine the data from both sheets into 1 but I would prefer to keep it separate. correspondingSHEET2 SHEET1
I have spent 8+ hours on this. I've tried index, match, vlookup, arrayformula, iferror, and combinations of the previous listed. The only thing I have been able to get accomplished is a headache. Aside from moving the data to the same sheet, I'm at a loss.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

My apologies, here is a link to a copy of my workbook. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1toWSiBFpNZT7wMnHf_V6Q6Ii7idrU2KEUIrKyz8zOPo/edit?usp=sharing


Added the formula to your test sheet:
=xlookup(B72,SHEET1!B:B,SHEET1!C:C,xlookup(B72,SHEET1!A:A,SHEET1!C:C,0))



The setup in Sheet1 is a bit odd with some of the codes listed in Column_A(due to merged cells) & some are in Column_B. I'd recommend to align them all within a single column as a good practice


Thank you for your help! I thought that might be my problem, it's how it downloads from the operating system I use at work and I didn't want to have to manipulate it every time I have to do this report. I truly appreciate your help!
